# set sink index in pulseaudio

Tags: linux, gnu, pulse-audio

Is there some configuration option to specify that X device should always grab sink index Y? Much like you can force a specific sound card driver to have a specific card index in alsa?

Failing that, is there some command to change the index of a sink at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think indexes were designed to be relied upon. If you need a reliable name for a source/sink, use a predetermined, unique *name*.

Oh, one other thing. Indexes seem to be autoincrementing, and are automatically adjusted if you remove a sink or source at runtime. So you would have to modify the PA sources to change indexes from their current behavior of just assigning a tracking number to sinks/sources, to being a *meaningful* datum. But doing that is redundant, since we already have a uniquely-identifying, meaningful field for sinks and sources: *name*.

Comment: Thanks. I use a library for my window manager (awesome) that relies on indices. I will propose this change to the maintainer.

Comment: I needed this to make my volume adjust script, which uses pactl, reliable when switching between HDMI and analog outputs. The sink ID increments every time.

Comment: My sink names change...